# Convert String to Array PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, string

Here is my question
I have a string `"[[10,20],[30,40],[50,30]]"` which can be converted into array by simply using `json_decode` which works fine for Numeric values but it's failing for string values like `"[S,M,L]"` which I handled using a simple logic

```
$string_value = str_replace(',', '","', $string_value);
$string_value = str_replace('[', '["', $string_value);
$string_value = str_replace(']', '"]', $string_value);
$string_value = json_decode($string_value);
```

this works fine for one dimentional Array like the one given above but in case of **2D Array** Like `[[red,green],[red],[red,blue]]` it's failing, is there another way of doing this

thanks in advance...

Comment: Well you could replace `["[` with `[[` and `]"]` with `]]` at the end

Comment: Why are you getting strings like that that aren't encoded properly?  I would look at the other end and fix it.

Comment: Trying to write your own parser for a non-standardized format, you'll always run into problems, exceptions, etc. Is there no way you can fix the input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A regex replacement would work to wrap all alphabetical characters in quotes:

```
$value = preg_replace( "(\w+)", '\'$0\'', $input );
```

Like so:

```
<?php

$input1 = "[[10,20],[30,40],[50,30]]";
$input2 = "[[red,green],[red],[red,blue]]";

$value1 = preg_replace( "(\w+)", '\'$0\'', $input1 );
$value2 = preg_replace( "(\w+)", '\'$0\'', $input2 );

echo $value1;
echo "<br />";
echo $value2;

?>
```

Gives me this output:

```
[['10','20'],['30','40'],['50','30']]
[['red','green'],['red'],['red','blue']]
```

Comment: @AbraCadaver fixed

Comment: Good idea, will deliver a solution, but this is not _yet_ an answer to the question!

Comment: This will not give you valid json, although that is easily fixed. The bigger problem will be the follow-up questions: Oh, but the string can contain spaces. And special characters. And of course, the keys can be strings was well ;-)

Comment: `[["'red'","'green'"],["'red'"],["'red'","'blue'"]]` my o/p

Answer (score 0):

To convert the string to a 1 Dimension Array fisrt remove the brackets and then only having a string separated by commas use the `explode` function:

```
$result=str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$original_string);
$result=explode(',',$result);
```

This can help is input are only 2D arrays:

```
$final_array=array();
// separate each brackets
$separate_in_arrays=explode(',',$osiginal_string);
foreach ($separate_in_array as $array) {
    $result=str_replace(array('[',']'),'',$array[0]);
    $result=explode(',',$result);
// Save result in a nested array
    $final_array[]=$result;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't work because there are nested arrays, this approach will flatten the array.

Comment: Yes indeed. This a solution to create a 1 dimensional array.

Comment: Editted solution to create a 2D Array from the sample string